# appended <input> not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a page, and i want to generate inputs for a form.

I do this with jquery:

```
function getval() {

    $('#UploadForm').empty();

    var limit = $("#GalleryCount").val();

    for(var i = 1;i<=limit;i++) {

        $('#UploadForm').append('<div class="imgOrderAdmin"><label for="file'+i+'">Image '+i+'</label><input type="file" name="file'+i+'" value="file'+i+'" /></div>');
    }
}
```

The elements do get added to the div with the ID #UploadForm but when the form is sendt, they do not get catched, it works when i add the  feild to the HTML page statically, as an exact same copy of what i am generating with JS.

PHP:

```
$i = 1;
while (!empty($_FILES['file'.$i]['name'])) {

    echo $_FILES['file'.$i]['name'];
    $i++;
}
```

HTML form propertise:

```
<form class="form-horizontal well" action="postAction.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Were is you `#UploadForm`? the new input but be added between the form tags

Comment: <div id="UploadForm"></div> is prior to the end </form> tag yes

Comment: Those aren't files....."file"+i contains no extension

Comment: What is the actual HTML that is generated.  Copy it from Dev window in chrome

Comment: @JohnDOe Hello OP - you did not tick an answer. Not sure what your involvement is on SO, but it's courteous to tick an answer if it resolved your issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently:

```
 $('<div class="imgOrderAdmin"><label for="file'+i+'">Image '+i+'</label><input type="file" name="file'+i+'" value="file'+i+'" /></div>').appendTo('#UploadForm');
```

OR

```
 $('form#UploadForm').append('<div class="imgOrderAdmin"><label for="file'+i+'">Image '+i+'</label><input type="file" name="file'+i+'" value="file'+i+'" /></div>');
```

should work.

By Adding the 'form' before '#UploadForm' you make sure the input is actually added to the form and not just the page outside the form.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons of security browsers do not allow programmatic assignment of `value` attribute for `input` elements with `type="file"`.

Imagine if this were possible. A malicious javascript would be able to upload (or at least try to upload) arbitrary files from users computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to make the name an array `name="file[i]"`

```
$('#UploadForm').append('<div class="imgOrderAdmin"><label for="file'+i+'">Image '+i+'</label><input type="file" name="file['+i+']" /></div>');
```

and in php

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($_FILES['file']);$i++){
  if(!empty($_FILES['file'][$i]['name'])) {
    echo $_FILES['file'][$i]['name'];
  }
}
```